# Openmp Reduction for operator "-"

Tags: c++, openmp

```
int main()
{
    int a=0;
    omp_set_num_threads(2);
    #pragma omp parallel reduction(+ : a)
    {
        a = omp_get_thread_num()+1;
    }
    std::cout << "Output:" << a;
    return 1;
}
```

I am getting wrong output using openmp reduction... For the following code, reduction(+) gives the output of sum of threadnum(), but when i mention reduction (-), it gives the same output... I am getting output as 3 for "+" and  "-".

Comment: I can only observe that nCOunt is initialized with 0, and each thread increments by 1 , so finally everything is added to make it 4. Still not getting why subtraction is not working

Comment: Yeah but on that case both +=1 and =1 gives the same output for nCOunt for the particular thread. And finally everything gets added because we have mentioned reduction(0) for that. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reduction in OpenMP functions as follows: each thread is given its local copy of the reduction variable and operations such as `+=` and `-=` affect the local copy. Then at the end the following reduction operation is performed:

```
a = init_value op a_0 op a_1 op a_2 op ... op a_(N-1)
```

where `N` is the number of threads and `init_value` is the initialisation value for the reduction operation. The initialisation value for both `+` and `-` reduction operations is 0 (zero). There is a catch with the subtraction though and it is explained in the OpenMP standard as a comment to the way that the final value is formed (§2.9.3.6 `reduction` clause):

> (The partial results of a subtraction reduction are added to form the final value.)

This means that with `reduction(-:a)` you still get all private values added together, i.e. both `+` and `-` reductions are equivalent. This is the correct way to implement it since it is assumed that the `-` reduction will only be coupled with the `var -= expr` or `var = var - expr` expressions. Therefore your program is not conforming to the standard and you get what you deserve for not reading into the intricate details of OpenMP.

The correct example with `reduction(-:a)` would be:

```
#pragma omp parallel reduction(-:a)
{
    a -= omp_get_thread_num() + 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the good answer.. You have mentioned it is explained in 2.9.3.6 clause, can you post the link of that...

Comment: Pick your particular version from here: http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-specifications/. §2.9.3.6 is specifically the section number in the OpenMP 3.1 standard. It is different in the older versions - just look for "reduction clause" in the contents.

Comment: This is a great answer so I feel bad for nitpicking but you said at the end "the following reduction operation is performed."  As far as I understand, the reduction is done without a barrier (nowait) on the for loop so the reduction is not all done at the end.  But maybe I'm wrong.  Of course that makes no difference to this particular problem.

Comment: The reduction is performed at the end of the parallel region. In you case this coincides with end of the loop since a combined `parallel for` construct is used. The order in which different partial results are used might depend on the order in which the different threads reach the region's end.

Answer (score 0):

Reduction with `-` is always tricky because of the non commutativity of the subtraction operator... You'd better off adding everything and then negating the result; it will be clear to anyone reading the code without having to resort to read the standard!

Comment: That's correct, i was exploring on the working of OpenMP and the result brought these doubts..